# There was an error deserializing the object of type <> The input source is not correctly formatted

Tags: c#, deserialization, uwp

I am trying to port my winform c# deskltop over to uwp.

In this part of my code I am calling a web api to return a serialized List.

It is also compressed.

This was the existing code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(URL);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri + route + "?" + COMPANY_REF + "=" + ApplicationObject.CompanyRef);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var result = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
string result2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
byte[] actualBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(result2.Replace("\"",""));                  
var myobj= Compression.DeSerialize(actualBytes);
```

my compression code:

```
public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] input)
{
    byte[] decompressedData;

    using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(input))
        {
            using (var zip = new GZipStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                zip.CopyTo(outputStream);
            }
        }
        decompressedData = outputStream.ToArray();
    }
    return decompressedData;
}
public static Object DeSerialize(this byte[] arrBytes)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var decompressed = Decompress(arrBytes);
        memoryStream.Write(decompressed, 0, decompressed.Length);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
    }
}
```

and my model:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("Groups"), XmlType("Groups")]
public class Groups
{
    public Groups()
    {
        group = new List<Group>();
    }

    [XmlElement("Group")]
    public List<Group> group { get; set; }
}
```

, XmlRoot("Group"), XmlType("Group")]
    public class Group
    {
        [XmlElement("GroupRef")]
        public Guid GroupRef;
        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string Name;
        [XmlElement("Description")]
        public string Description;
    }

Now porting this over to UWP I have this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(Shared.URL);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/text"));
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri + route + "?" + GeneralTags.COMPANY_REF + "=" + ApplicationObject.CompanyRef);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var result = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
string result2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result);
byte[] actualBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(result2.Replace("\"", ""));                  
var myobj = Compression.DeSerialize<InformedWorker.Models.Group>(actualBytes);
```

my compression code:

```
public static byte[] Compress(byte[] input)
{
    byte[] compressesData;

    using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var zip = new GZipStream(outputStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            zip.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
        }

        compressesData = outputStream.ToArray();
    }
    return compressesData;
}
public static T DeSerialize<T>(byte[] arrBytes)
{
    var decompressed = Decompress(arrBytes);
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(decompressed))
    {
        using (XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(memoryStream, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max))
        {
            DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)dcs.ReadObject(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

and my model:

```
public class Groups
{
    public Groups()
    {
        group = new List<Group>();
    }

    [XmlElement("Group")]
    public List<Group> group { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    [XmlElement("GroupRef")]
    public Guid GroupRef;
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name;
    [XmlElement("Description")]
    public string Description;
}
```

note:
i was not allowed to use ' [Serializable~ '  so I had to remove.

Also, I could not find BinaryFormatter so had to use 'DataContractSerializer' instead.

It errors on this line:

```
return (T)dcs.ReadObject(reader);
```

and the error is:

```
There was an error deserializing the object of type  The input source is not correctly formatted.
```

I am using this approach so that I can compress my data from server to client.

Any ideas as to how to get this to work please?

thanks

ADDITIONAL:

This is the XML I am compressing/sending from server:

```
<Groups>
  <Group>
    <GroupId>1</GroupId>
    <GroupRef>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</GroupRef>
    <Name>Todays Work</Name>
    <Description>System</Description>
    <CompanyRef>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</CompanyRef>    
    <Active>1</Active>
  </Group>
  <Group>
    <GroupId>2</GroupId>
    <GroupRef>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</GroupRef> 
    <Name>All</Name>
    <Description>System</Description>
    <CompanyRef>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</CompanyRef> 
    <Active>1</Active>
  </Group>
</Groups>
```

Comment: Post the xml string.

Comment: @jdweng Could you confirm how I would do that?  I added :  var contents =  reader.ReadContentAsString(); but content came back as empty.  The byte array has values though?

Comment: @jdweng added the original XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

await the ReadAsByteArraysAsync.  The code will not continue to the next line until the data is read in

```
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
```